# iOS development - WebPage SourceCode

Tags: ios, html

Is there a url (.txt)  for the source code of each website?

If not, how can i get the source code of a webpage and be able to show it in a UITextView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
NSString *googleString = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *googleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:googleString];
NSError *error;
NSString *googlePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:googleURL
                            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                error:&error];
```

This will put the contents of the google home page into `googlePage` and, if applicable, the error into `error`. If the page being loaded uses Unicode characters, try `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of `NSASCIIStringEncoding`.